# Footer will not use 100% of width

Tags: html, css, footer

My footer, along with the wrapper and body, are set to 100% page width, yet for some reason the footer has a small (25px or so) gap on the right side.  I've tried moving it out of the wrapper, but that didn't work.  The body already has margin and padding set to 0.
I don't have this issue with the header.

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/w63Jk/

Any thoughts as to how I could fix this?

Comment: This code isn't enough. Please share the whole page and css.

Comment: Could be your shadows...is the space you are concerned with in addition to the 'black-box' that defines the shadow?

Comment: That should work, maybe you need to reset  `body, html {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`

Comment: works in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YcKbG/ what are the html and body elements up to?

Comment: Uploaded the problem onto jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/w63Jk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing the `width` from your `#header` works:

```
#header {
    padding:5px;
    /* width: 100%; */
    background-color:#272727;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;

}
```

That's because paddings are adding additional width to the element, if you've defined one in your CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/w63Jk/2/

Works in IEs, FFs and Chrome.

Info: Block elements such as DIVs always have the full available width of their parent by default, if no other widths defined via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Some other element's padding is probably affecting your footer's width. You should verify that both body and html have margin and padding set to 0:

```
*, html, body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```

If this doesn't fix it, I'd assume that some other element's inherited/inherent margin or padding is borking your footer. (`p`, `div`, and so on.) Try opening your webpage in Firefox and use Firebug to, or Chrome and use developer tools, to see what CSS might be affecting you.

(Another thing to consider: could it possibly be a layering or inheritance issue? Do you have multiple CSS files?)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, Here is what I did

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="footer">
            Hii
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS :**

```
body{
background:red;
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;}


#wrapper{background:green;
width:100%;
padding:0;
height:100%;
margin:0;
position:absolute;}

#footer {
background:#272727;
width:100%;
height:40px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
margin-top:20px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 20px  black;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 20px black;
 box-shadow: 0 0px 20px  black;
}​
```

And it is working fine. Check your code and make changes accordingly.
[Follow the link](http://jsfiddle.net/sumitsharma/sJ9es/) for code on jsFiddle.