# I want the footer to completely cover the bottom

Tags: html, css

I want my footer to completely cover the bottom but ıt keeps giving me space from the left. you can see my code snippet. i still couldnt figure it out unforteunatly. thanks for all your help

I want my footer to completely cover the bottom but ıt keeps giving me space from the left. you can see my code snippet. i still couldnt figure it out unforteunatly. thanks for all your help

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;

}

html{
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
#navbar{
    color: #ffff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 0.75rem;
    height: 70px;
}
#navbar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#navbar ul li a {
    padding: 0.7rem;
}
#navbar ul li a:hover {
    background: rgb(226, 109, 128);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#home{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
#home img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
#home .name h2{
    margin-bottom: 0.74rem;
}
#home .name p{
    opacity: 0.5;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:larger;
    
}
/* home a ve home hover kısmı hakkımda kısmı */
#education{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1rem;
}
#education .items{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
#education .items .item{
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
#education .items .item:hover{
    color:palevioletred
}
#education .education-image{
    padding: 1rem;
}

#about{
    color: #333;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.about{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.p h3{
    text-align: center;
    word-spacing: 5px;
}
 .abouts .about{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
 }
 .abouts .about .about-image{
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
 }
 .abouts .about .about-image{
    border-radius: 50px;
 }
 img.yuvarlak{
    border-radius: 100%;
 }

 @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");

 .footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: #3586ff;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .social-icon,
  .menu {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .social-icon__item,
  .menu__item {
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  .social-icon__link {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .social-icon__link:hover {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  
  .menu__link {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.75;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  
  .menu__link:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .footer p {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 15px 0 10px 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  
  .wave {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: url("https://i.ibb.co/wQZVxxk/wave.png");
    background-size: 1000px 100px;
  }
  
  .wave#wave1 {
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    animation: animateWaves 4s linear infinite;
  }
  
  .wave#wave2 {
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0.5;
    bottom: 10px;
    animation: animate 4s linear infinite !important;
  }
  
  .wave#wave3 {
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 0.2;
    bottom: 15px;
    animation: animateWaves 3s linear infinite;
  }
  
  .wave#wave4 {
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0.7;
    bottom: 20px;
    animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes animateWaves {
    0% {
      background-position-x: 1000px;
    }
    100% {
      background-positon-x: 0px;
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes animate {
    0% {
      background-position-x: -1000px;
    }
    100% {
      background-positon-x: 0px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<head>

</head>
<body>
     <header class="bg-dark-blue">
        <div class="container">
            <nav id="navbar">
            <h1 class="heading-small"> Buse Nur Çetin</h1>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">Ana Sayfa</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Hakkımda</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">İletişim</a></li>
                <li><a href="#education">Eğitim</a></li>
              </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
     </header>
     <section id="home">
        <img src="images/me1.jpeg" alt="Buse Nur Çetin" width="270px">
        <div class="name text-center">
            <h2 class="heading-big">Buse Nur Çetin</h2>
            <p>Student | Developer | Genius </p>
        </div>

        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-dark">Hakkımda?</a>

     </section>
     <section id= "education" class="bg-dark-blue">
        <h3 class="text-center heading-medium">Ben Kimim?</h3>
        <div class="items">
            <article class="item">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-school"></i>
                <h3>Okul Eğitimleri</h3>
                <p>Okul Eğitimlerimi Görmek İçin Tıklayınız.

                </p>
            </article>

            <article class="item">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-dumbbell"></i>
                <h3>Yaptığım Sporlar</h3>
                <p>Yaptığım Sporları Görmek İçin Tıklayınız.

                </p>
            </article>

            <article class="item">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-medal"></i>
                <h3>Sertifikalar</h3>
                <p>Sertifikalarımı Görmek İçin Tıklayınız.

                </p>
            </article>

        </div>

     </section >
     <section id="about">
        <h3 class="text-center heading-medium">Hakkımda</h3>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="about">
                <!-- hakkımda -->
                <div class="about">
                   <div class="about-image">
                      
                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                
                   </div>
                   <div class="about-info">
                    <p><h3> Ben Buse Nur Çetin
                         
                    </div><br>
                    
                    <div class="education">
                        <div id="education"></div>
                        <h3 class="text-center heading-medium">Sertifikalar</h3>
                        <div class="education">
                            <div style="text-align:center ;">
                            <div class="education-image">
                                <img src="images/sertifika1.jpeg" alt="Sertifika" width="200px" height="200px" class="yuvarlak" >
                                
                                <div style="text-align:center ;">
                                    <h3> YEA Akademi Sertifikası</h3>
                                </div> <br>

                     <div class="contact">
                        <h1 class="text-center heading- medium">İletişim</h1> <br>
                        
                        
                            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/busenurcetin16/" target="_blank">
                             <img src="images/insta.jpeg" width="50px"class="yuvarlak" ></a>

                             <a href="mailto:busenurcet@gmail.com" target="_blank" class="yuvarlak">
                                <img src="images/gmail.jpeg" width="100px"class="yuvarlak" alt="">
                             </a>
                             <a href="https://twitter.com/busenurcetin16" target="_blank" >
                                <img src="images/twitter.png" width="50px"class="yuvarlak" ></a>

                              <!--footer --> 

                              
                                <footer class="footer">
                                  <div class="waves">
                                    <div class="wave" id="wave1"></div>
                                    <div class="wave" id="wave2"></div>
                                    <div class="wave" id="wave3"></div>
                                    <div class="wave" id="wave4"></div>
                                  </div>
                                  <ul class="social-icon">
                                    <li class="social-icon__item"><a class="social-icon__link" href="#">
                                        <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
                                      </a></li>
                                    <li class="social-icon__item"><a class="social-icon__link" href="#">
                                        <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
                                      </a></li>
                                    <li class="social-icon__item"><a class="social-icon__link" href="#">
                                        <ion-icon name="logo-linkedin"></ion-icon>
                                      </a></li>
                                    <li class="social-icon__item"><a class="social-icon__link" href="#">
                                        <ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon>
                                      </a></li>
                                  </ul>
                                  <ul class="menu">
                                    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                                    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">About</a></li>
                                    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Services</a></li>
                                    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Team</a></li>
                                    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                              
                                  </ul>
                                  <p>&copy;2021 Nadine Coelho | All Rights Reserved</p>
                                </footer>
                                <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
                                <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
                                                        
                              <!--bitiş footer-->
                    
                        
                        <div class="contact">
                            <div id="contact"></div>
                            <div style="text-align:center ;"></div>
                        </div>
                     </div>           
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

     </section>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Footer will not use 100% of width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985225/footer-will-not-use-100-of-width), more than likely you need to remove padding from the body or some container element of your footer.

Comment: Can you supply a codePen?

Comment: Have you used your browser dev tools inspect facility to see exactly who/where is setting a margin or padding or something to the footer? My guess is that you haven't removed the browser's default margin setting. But you haven't shown us any CSS - are you using some library/framework?

Comment: There is so many things wrong with this html, one of which is why is your `footer` inside your home `section` tag?

Comment: hello im new on coding so i dont know many things thats my first landing page i've ever made @SinisaM

Comment: I voted to close this question because the code sample is too long. Please [edit] your post to reduce your code to a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).